# NLTK Chunk Parser: How to escape special characters

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger, text-chunking

So I am trying to extract some info from text and i am using NLTK chunking.

Here is my input

`The stocks show 67% rise, last year it was 12% fall`

i want to capture

`67% rise` and `12% fall`

POS Tagging the above sentence shows

```
('The', 'DT'), ('stocks', 'NNS'), ('show', 'VBP'), ('67', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('rise', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('last', 'JJ'), ('year', 'NN'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('12', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('fall', 'NN')
```

Now, i came up with a simple rule

`Stat: {<CD><NN>(<NN>+|<VBN>|JJ)?}`

which works well and captures

```
('67', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('rise', 'NN')

('12', 'CD'), ('%', 'NN'), ('fall', 'NN')
```

but in my data set, i have stuff like

`5 million dollars`

which is

`('5', 'CD'), ('man', 'NN'), ('stock', 'NN')`

and is also incorrectly captured. So i thought of including the `%` sign in my rule

`Stat: {<CD><%>(<NN>+|<VBN>|JJ)?}`

but this rule does not match anything now. How do i escape/include `%` in my chunk rule?

**Update**

So, what i do not understand is that i can match other special characters. For example, if i have a rule as

`XYZ:{<:>}`

this matches all the `:`s in the input. So all I am trying to do is

`XYZ:{<%>}`

and this does not work. I have tried to escape the `%` by

`XYZ:{<\%>}`

but this does not work either. I tried `\\` but to no avail. I really do not want to modify the input string as once i have matched, i want to find out the indices of the matched strings. So if i modify the input string, that will throw off my indices unless i do a reverse transformation first

Comment: I think you can't match the text (`%`), only its tags (oddly, `NN`). If you get another POS tagger which gives you a distinct tag for `%`, then you might be able to improve the chunker.

Comment: will i be able to use nltk's chunker with other POS taggers? does nltk have other pos taggers available? or should i go for something like stanford pos taggers?

Comment: @lenz is there a way to specify a rule such as `NN that matches the string %`?

Comment: If the tagger's tagset is the same as in your chunk rules, then you can use any tagger, even one from outside NLTK (or Python altogether).

Comment: There might be a way to specify the token, not just it's tag, but I couldn't find anything about that in the docs. In any case, this has nothing to do with escaping. Maybe you should reword the question (and its title), or post a new question altogether to get the right people's attention.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since its a regular expression you could just escape it.

```
Stat: {<CD><\%>(<NN>+|<VBN>|JJ)?}
```

You could also have a list of keywords you want to replace, so that your chunk rules don't become excessively long.

e.g.

```
s = '56% rise and 75% fall'
gen_replacements = [('%', 'PERCENTAGE'), ('perc.', 'PERCENTAGE'), etc]
for ndl, rpl in gen_replacements:
    s = s.replace(' %s ' % ndl, ' %s ' % rpl)

Stat: {<CD><PERCENTAGE>(<NN>+|<VBN>|JJ)?}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're familiar with the way the ChunkParser interprets the chunk expressions, which operate on tagged text?

Comment: lenz: Could you ellaborate? My latter suggestion? That was not given as a working example but as a suggestion. I do not personally use NLTK but Pattern, reading through NLTKs documentation, it seemed feasible to include such characters such as % by escaping them as it is stated that the rules are mere regexes.

Comment: They're not mere regexes – otherwise, `<NN>+` would be interpreted as *"one lower-than, two N's, and one or more greater-than's"*, instead of *"one or more nouns"*. There is an additional translation step. And they are applied to the sequence of tags, not the text itself.

Comment: Btw: please use "@" in front of my name so I get a notification when you ask me something here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pattern like 
<*CD*><*NN*>+